# Gem / Metasploit Install error: An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.4)

Tags: ruby, macos, postgresql, metasploit

Keep getting the attached error when trying to install metasploit dependant gems on OS X EL Capitan. Have tried reinstalling postgres etc, not sure how to fix this is issue.

```
An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.4'` succeeds before bundling.
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZB4l.png)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and following steps worked wonder for me,

1. First thing is updating your Xcode Tools as you are on Mac OX.
2. Then install Postgre via `Homebrew`. ([Here is a link on guidelines](https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-postgresql-on-a-mac-with-homebrew-and-lunchy/))

You'll need to uninstall it first,

```
brew uninstall postgresql
```

or you can update it with

```
brew update
```

3. And reinstall with

   brew install postgresql
4. Now you can run, `gem install pg` successfully.

Let me know if I'm missing on something.

Answer (score 0):

```
1) install postgresql
2) install postgresql-dev
2) install gem install pg
```